# Preprocessor message containing macro

Tags: c, printing, macros, c-preprocessor, pragma

How can I print a message containing macros during preprocessing?

E.g.:

```
#define MACRO_1  1
#pragma message ("Date:" __DATE__)           // OK
#pragma message ("MACRO_1 = " MACRO_1)       // error: pragma message requires parenthesized string
```

Comment: I'd guess the result of MACRO_1 just needs to be a string ("1") in order for this to work. You can stringify it in the code with `#pragma message ("MACRO_1 = " #MACRO_1)`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: @IdeaHat - I tried to use a "1" string, to use the single #, but I keep getting the same error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is to stringize the preprocessor MACRO_1 after being expanded. You can not insert #MACRO_1 into #pragma message() as strays are forbidden. In that case, what the preprocessor is seeing inside #pragma message() is "#MACRO_1" and not "1". However, when you use SSTRINGIZE(x) (as shown in the example below) you are instructing the preprocessor to expand MACRO_1 (get its value which is 1 in your case) and then stringize it (covert it into string). Finally, you will obtain the string "1" inside #pragma message() at the end.

Please try this code, it should print what you intend to do.

```
#define MACRO_1  1
#pragma message ("Date:" __DATE__)           
#define STRINGIZE(x) "MACRO_1 = " #x
#define SSTRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE(x)
#pragma message (SSTRINGIZE(MACRO_1))
```

Comment: This is what I get from your code:   `warning: MACRO_1 = MACRO_1 [-W#pragma-messages]`

Comment: I reviewed the code, the one shown now should work. Hope this helps :)